# Trying to access source device from boost::iostreams

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

I wrote a custom source device that counts the bytes read so far:

```
class socket_stream_source : public boost::iostreams::source
{
public:

    int readSoFar=0;

    socket_stream_source(socket_ptr sock) : _sock(sock)
    {

    }

    std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n)
    {
        int readCount = _sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(s, n));
        readSoFar += readCount;
        return readCount;
    }

private:
    socket_ptr _sock;

};
```

I'm using it like this:

```
boost::iostreams::stream<socket_stream_source> in(sock);
```

How can I access my readSoFar variable ?

Or is there another way to count the bytes read so far from an istream ?

Comment: You made it public so you can get it like this: in.readSoFar.

Comment: I tried that before, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the device access operators provided by boost::iostreams::stream, i.e.

```
T& operator*();
T* operator->();
```

In your code this suffice:

```
in->readSoFar;
```